# Caption of images on wikipedia pages

Tags: python, text, nlp, wikipedia

I'm looking to check the caption(text below each image) on a wikipedia article. I wish to parse those strings (mostly using regex) and then if it matches, I want to save the link of that image.

I've been importing wikipedia directly to parse text, but after looking around the net I saw I'd need a different kind of parser for that. I tried using mwparserfromhell and pywikibot, but I couldn't resolve the pywikibot errors for me and just mwparserfromhell gives me empty results.

Any help in doing the above, without using DBPpedia?

Comment: Have tou tried the wikipedia dump? I suggest to you the specific dump for elasticsearch https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/current/ . You could index all wikipedia articles there and operate on es with api of several languages. The python api for es are awesome and you could integrate in your code every parser for python

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this @someone1?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote up to do that

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
    parse.py

    MediaWiki API Demos
    Demo of `Parse` module: Parse content of a page

    MIT License
"""

import requests
from pprint import pprint

S = requests.Session()

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"

page_title= "Photosynthesis"
PARAMS = {
    "action": "parse",
    "page": page_title,
    "format": "json"
}

R = S.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
DATA = R.json()
page = (DATA["parse"]["text"]["*"])
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
thumb_divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "thumbinner"})

images = []
for div in thumb_divs:
    image = div.findAll("img")[0]['src']
    caption = div.findAll("div")[0].text

    image_and_caption = {
        'image_url' : image,
        'image_caption' : caption
    }
    images.append(image_and_caption)

return_value = {'term' : page_title, 'images' : images }

pprint(return_value)
```